# How strong is the Schröder–Bernstein theorem where one set is the natural numbers?

Tags: set-theory, constructive-mathematics

The full Schröder-Bernstein theorem states that given an injection from A to B and also one from B to A, there is a bijection between A and B. It is equivalent to excluded middle, as shown in the paper [Cantor–Bernstein implies Excluded Middle](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09193) by Pierre Pradic and Chad E. Brown, a result which has been formalized in at least two proof systems.

How strong is the theorem if we set A to the set of all natural numbers (and continue to allow B to be any set)? So far our best result is that given this case of Schröder–Bernstein plus the Limited Principle of Omniscience (LPO), we can prove excluded middle. There is an [informal proof described here](https://github.com/metamath/set.mm/issues/2595#issuecomment-1157389136) which [has been formalized in metamath](https://us.metamath.org/ileuni/sbthom.html) — to summarize it is a direct consequence of Lemma 3.2 from the Pradic–Brown paper ("Suppose that we have an omniscient set O and some sets A and B. If there exists a surjection f : O → A + B, then either A is inhabited or it is empty." where + is disjoint union).

Is a better result known? Also, is LPO→excluded middle equivalent to some better known principle, for example in the pantheon of LPO, LLPO, MP, etc.?

For the sake of concreteness, I'll ask with respect to a constructive set theory such as IZF, although my impression is that similar results hold in other foundations.

Comment: What is your base theory?

Comment: The base theory is IZF (intuitionistic Zermelo Fraenkel) set theory

Comment: As a partial result, it is known that Kleene's first realizability model satisfies $\mathsf{MP}$ but it does not satisfy the Schroder-Bernstein theorem for $\mathbb{N}$. (For example, the set of all Halting problems $K$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, and we can embed $\mathbb{N}$ into $K$, but there is no bijection between them.) Thus Schroder-Bernstein for $\mathbb{N}$ does not follow from $\mathsf{MP}$.